# Why does changing to polar coordinates makes the computation of limits much "easier"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

> Let $f \colon D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $(0, 0)$ an accumulation point of $D$. Then the
> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = \lim_{r \to 0} f(r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta}) $$
> where $(r, \theta)$ are the polar coordinates of the point $(x, y)$.

This was taught to me in class without any form of justification. Also I was taught that if I were to calculate the limit in any point $(a, b)$, then I should take $u = x - a$, $v = y - b$ and $g(u, v) = f(x - a, y - b)$ and prove the limit of $g(u ,v)$ in $(0, 0)$. This approach however does not work in the case in which one of the components of $(a, b)$ is infinity. Lets assume that $a = \infty$. What I thought of doing was to make the substitution $s = 1/x$, and make the iniftiniy into a zero, then do the algorithm that we were taught. But it still puzzled me why polar coordinates fail when we go to infinity. So  here I am presenting a proof that I made up and that I don't know whether or not it is rigorous.

So firstly, I analyzed why the polar coordinates fail. Firstly, for all real numbers $a$, the points $(\infty, a)$, would all be one single point, namely $(r=\infty, \theta = 0)$ and if we let $\theta$ be non-zero, let's assume between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then all those values of $\theta$ would represent the same point, namely $(\infty, \infty)$.

But, why do the polar coordinates work in the first place. My initial guess, was that if we look at a map $$g\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0)\} \to \ \mathbb{R}^* \times (-\pi, \pi\,], g(x, y) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, atan2(y, x))$$
then $g$ is both continuous and bijective ($atan2$ gives us the angle made with the positive $Ox$ axis).

Why I would assume we make this substitution is because of the definition of the limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the Euclidian topology, namely if $f\colon D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, y) = l \\
\iff \\
\forall U \in \mathbb{V}(l) \colon \exists V \in \mathbb{V}((a, b))\colon \forall x \in D\colon x \in V \text{\\} \{(a, b)\} \implies f(x) \in U \\
\iff \\
\forall \epsilon > 0\colon \exists \delta > 0\colon \forall(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\colon \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} < \delta \implies |f(x, y) - l| < \epsilon
$$

So if we take $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then it is sufficient to take the limit as only the one variable $r$ approches $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

To formalize my argument, I shall say that I am looking for a function $$h\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0)\} \to \ \mathbb{R}^* \times A, h(x, y) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, t(x, y)),\\ t\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that $h$ is both bijective and continuous.

The assumption that $h$ is continuous is very intuitive, because if it were not surjective, then we could not reach certain points (in my example above $(r = \infty, \theta = 0.1)$) and if it were not injective then for any function the limit in $(\infty, 0)$ would have the same value as in $(\infty, 3)$. Why I think continuity is important is because we have to preserve the limits.

Now if we extend this concept, let's assume there is
$$h\colon \overline{\mathbb{R}}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0)\} \to \ (0, \infty] \times A, h(x, y) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, t(x, y)),\\ t\colon \overline{\mathbb{R}}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that $h$ is both bijective and continuous and $A$ is a subset of the extended real numbers. ($\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty, \infty] = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty \}$ is the extended real number line).

Now we can't work with metric spaces, because how do we define the distance between $0$ and $\infty$?(From my course, the codomain of a metric is $[0, \infty)$, not $[0, \infty]$), so I will be working with topological spaces.

The function $s\colon \overline{\mathbb{R}}^2 \to (0, \infty]$ is continuous, therefore $t$ has to be continuous, since the canonical projection is continuous. Now we let $B_r = \{ (x, y) \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}^2 | \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r \} \text{for } r \in (0, \infty]$. Take $r < \infty$ and look at the image of $B_r$ through $h$. If $a \in B_r$, then $h(a) = (r, t(a))$. But because $t$ is bijective the image of $B_r$ through $t$ has to be $A$. Now if we take $r = \infty$, then $$B_{\infty} \text{would be} \{(x, y) \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}^2 \text{\\} \{(0, 0) \} | x = \pm \infty \text{ OR } y = \pm \infty\} $$
which is a closed set(can be written as the union of $4$ closed sets).

I think we could get a contradiction if we show that $B_r$ and $B_{\infty}$ are not homeomorphic, but they kinda should be, because their image through a continuous function is the same. I do not know what to do from here. I am studying engineering, so I do not have a very large background in pure maths, but this is what I came up with? Can this be continued to a meaningful result?
Another concern is why we don't get a contradiction when $r=0$, because we can't make a bijection with the origin, by taking as a first component $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?(a reason might be because when we study limits, we only care what happens to the inputs in a neighborhood excluding the point we are approaching towards, but I do not know how to make the argument rigurous).

Also, when doing substitutions, like I did with $h(x)$. In order to preserve limits, does it have to be bijective and continuous(like I assumed?). It seems intuitive, but I do not know how to formalize the reason behind this restriction.

Comment: Sorry, your post is too long for me to go through it all. I just wanted to make one point: what's important is not so much "polar coordinates" as "$(x,y)$ is close to $(0,0)$" and we measure distance by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which happens to be one of the parts of polar coordinates.  Limits are all about describing behavior when you are close to the limit point (in your case, $(0,0)$), so even without knowing polar coordinates, you could think about $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ as $\lim_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0} f(x,y)$.

Comment: Please focus on one question only and try to make your post shorter.